# Minimize number of groups, where sum of group elements is below certain value

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

Let's say I have a list of 10 items and a max_sum:

```
items = [1, 2, 4, 4, 10, 10, 15, 18, 21, 22]
max_sum = 30
```

I want to group the elements in `items`, and I want to find the minimum number of groups, provided that the sum of elements in each group is less than a pre-set value, `max_sum`, where all elements of `items` are less than `max_sum`.

General idea for algorithm:

- initialize 1) empty list `new_group`, 2) float `space_left` in group `=(max_sum - sum(new_group))`
- find largest item, such that item <= space_left
- append largest item to `new_group`
- update `space_left`
- remove item from `items`
- once `min(items)` > `space_left`, start over
- count cycles to find minimum number of groups

So for the values given, this algorithm would yield 4 groups:

```
[22, 4, 4]
[21, 2, 1]
[18, 10]
[15, 10]
```

I think my above approach will work but am wondering if there is a more direct/better way. Thanks!

Comment: You should check out https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bin_packing_problem, it is the exact question you have and there has already been a lot of research in this area.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach will not work. You use a greedy algorithm that may lead to unused space in some groups. E.g.:

```
 items = [13, 11, 10, 10, 9, 7]
 max_sum = 30

 First group  => [13, 11] (leaving a diff of 6)
 Second group => [10, 10, 9] (leaving a diff of 1)
 Third group  => [7]
```

Here it would obviously be better to partiton as

```
First group  => [13, 10, 7]
Second group => [11, 10, 9]
```

As noted in a comment, this is the well-known bin packing problem. If you want even further reading, you can have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) in addition to the link provided in the comment.